# Can I upgrade Mac OS with forgotten firmwarepasswd from AppStore?

Tags: macos, firmware, macos-catalina

I forgot my MacBook Pro 2015(macOS Sierra, 10.12.6) firmwarepasswd and would like to upgrade the OS to Catalina. Will upgrading from App Store trigger the firmwarepasswd prompt after installation/booting?

Comment: Why not just take it to the Apple Store to get it unlocked *before* risking it. Of course, it *should* all go smoothly, but not for everybody, especially jumping all the way from 10.12 to 10.15 in one step… if it will even let you. You might need to go to High Sierra first. You also need a solid backup.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I took it to the Apple Store but the original receipt was requested, which I don't have access to.
Only have the stamped and signed sales invoice, I bought it during a company's sell-off. Apple Store ain't acknowledging the sales invoice.
I've contacted the company but they can't find the original receipt too.

Comment: A 2015 doesn't have a T2 chip, so you might be able to get round it. Not something I've ever tried, but see https://osxdaily.com/2015/01/28/forgot-mac-firmware-password-what-now/

Answer (score 0):

@Tetsujin recommendation actually worked. I tried bumping to 10.15 directly twice but both attempts failed. However, when I jumped to 10.14 (Mojave) first, then upgrade to 10.15, it was successful.

It didn't ask for the firmwarepasswd while installing but asked for my iCloud password after boot. I now run 10.15!